# Paypal transaction fees deduct from each account equally - how?

Tags: paypal

I am using a Paypal adaptive payment method. I am selling products in a multi vendor store. Now the problem is all the transaction fee of the Paypal only deducts from my account (business account) and not from other sellers account. why is it that, why not deduct equal amount from each account?

Also is it possible to only deduct fees from others account and not from business account?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about programming, but about the payment policy and/or configuration of Paypal. This question should be directed at Paypal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the FEESPAYER parameter in the [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) request.

[image]